# SDL2 Threads C++ pointer corruption

Tags: multithreading, pointers, sdl-2, heap-corruption

So, i have the following problem which may seem pretty strange or too elementary. This code snippet demonstrates my problem.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int doSTH(void* data){

    int* data2 = (int*)data;
    cout << data2 << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main(){

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    int* data = new int(2);
    cout << data << endl;
    SDL_CreateThread(doSTH, "sth", (void*)data);
    SDL_Delay(1);
    delete data;
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Output is

```
0x2479f40
0x400c05
```

That means that somehow the function i call doesn't get the pointer i give it, am i missing something?

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.8 and codeblocks.
Please tell me if i should give any more info. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell that should not happen. Use `std::thread` or `std::async` instead of `SDL_CreateThread`, which works correctly and incidentally saves you from `void *` casting.

Comment: i have heard rumors that STL threads are slow on some platforms, that's why i don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, somehow the build of SDL2 was screwed up. I just uninstalled libx11-dev, rebooted and then reinstalled libsdl2-dev and now it works correctly.

Comment: just for info: i just installed a new wine version through playonlinux and my libsdl2 is screwed up and the above is no solution anymore